# Elementor not showing updates

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I'm using Elementor on a WordPress website, including the pro version and all the latest updates. The issue is that when I'm logged in as an admin, I can see the changes made to the page, but if I access it from incognito mode or another device, the changes are not visible. I've tried using presets from LiteSpeed Cache, optimizing the site, and searching for solutions online, but I haven't found any fixes. Has anyone else experienced this problem and found a solution? Thanks, I'm looking forward to hearing your thoughts.

regenerate css in settings of elementor, purge all css with lite speed cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Elementor > Tools > General, and click on the "Regenerate CSS" button. This will regenerate the CSS files for your site and may resolve any caching issues.

[image: show the above text path in this picture]

If you're using other caching plugins besides LiteSpeed Cache, try disabling them temporarily to see if they are causing the issue.

Disable all other plugins: Temporarily disable all other plugins on your site to see if one of them is causing the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I tried this method and unfortunately it doesn't want to work. I disabled all plug-ins, except for Elementor, and I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you cleared the cache of the cache plugin you're using on your site.

Another solution could be to check if your hosting is using a cache system too, like for example Siteground and Cloudways. If so you should clear the cache directly from the hosing panel.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, I solved it, the whole thing was from the cache. The whole thing was from the litespeed cache, after I installed another plugin for emptying the cache, the litespeed folder was rewritten.